# Срез DataFrame с сохранением типа DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Часто в pandas при выборке одного столбца срезом DataFrame бывает полезно сохранить тип результирующего объекта DataFrame. По умолчанию pandas конвертирует результат в Series.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [1, 2, 3]})
df['a']

0    1
1    2
2    3
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

Самое просто, что приходит в голову, это следующее:

```
df['a'].to_frame()
```

Но этот вариант не по фен-шую. Мне кажется должен существовать, и где-то я это видел, более изящный прием?

Comment: можете уточнить что именно вы хотите сохранить - тип данных или сами данные? Если данные то в каком формате?

Comment: Тип данных. Т.е. результат должен быть такой же как и в приведенном выше примере, но только не в видк Series, а в виде DataFrame. Полный аналог  df['a'].to_frame()  .

Comment: тип данных - это `int64` в вашем примере, поэтому я и попросил уточнить... Если сохранить нужно DataFrame, то `series.to_frame(name="column_name")` - вполне себе идиоматичный способ

Answer (score 2):

Просто используйте `df[['a']]`. Вроде это то, что требуется.

Answer (score 2):

```
df.loc[:, 'a'] - вернёт pandas.core.series.Series # передана строка
df.loc[:, ['a']] - вернёт pandas.core.frame.DataFrame # передан лист
```